# Silverlight 3: Event trigger argues that attribute is out of range

Tags: wpf, silverlight, eventtrigger

I want to make a grid non-transparent when mouse enters. So I try to catch MouseEnter event and animate Opactity property

```
    <Grid  Opacity="0.1" Name="myGrid" >
            <Grid.Triggers>
                <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Grid.MouseEnter"  >
                    <BeginStoryboard>
                        <Storyboard>
                            <DoubleAnimation From="0.1" To="1" Duration="00:00:01" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" Storyboard.TargetName="myGrid"/>
                        </Storyboard>
                    </BeginStoryboard>
                </EventTrigger>
            </Grid.Triggers>
    </Grid>
```

But InitializeComponent argues that Grid.MouseEnter attribute is out of range. What I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Your code worked here.

I use Visual Studio 2010 and pasted your code in to a C# WPF Application.

Comment: Thank you, but Silverlight 3 App doesn't :(

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify the event as MouseEnter instead of Grid.MouseEnter